# Some Packages not Running on R Version 1.0.153

Tags: r, process, rstudio, r-package

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of R Studio Version 1.0.153. However in the previous version the packages **processmapR** and **DiagrammeR** were getting installed easily but now the after installing and loading the package, this is the error I am getting. Please help me.

```
install.packages("processmapR")
library(processmapR)

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called ‘DiagrammeR’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘processmapR’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘processmapR’
```

Comment: So, you need to install package **DiagrammeR**.

Comment: Hi Prive, Again, getting this error:                                                        
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'grDevices' 3.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'DiagrammeR'
* removing 'C:/Users/ashminkaul/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/DiagrammeR'

Comment: Restart your R session and try again.

Comment: Won't help Sir, tried it. please see this page, I am trying to follow it on my newer version but errors are persisting:                                                         => https://www.bupar.net/about.html

Comment: I've installed all 6 packages without any problem. And loaded package **processmapR**. Which version of R (not RStudio) do you have (check with `sessionInfo()`)? You may need to have R 3.4.0 for some reason.

Comment: Yes, for whatever reason the newest version of the DiagrammeR package requires `grDevices` 3.4.0 (you can confirm at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiagrammeR/index.html, where it does indeed import `grDevices (>= 3.4.0)`, which is only provided with R 3.4.0 and above)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin for your help and also to F. Prive. I downloaded the R compiler from cran version 3.4.1 and it ran perfectly.